# How to add tool tip to "inline" hyperlink

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a TextBlock control in my UWP app and inside it I have several text and hyperlinks. I shorten the urls of the hyperlinks when showing to user but I want to add a tooltip that shows the full url when user hovers over hyperlink.

I know how to add tool tips to controls but in this case Hyperlink object is not a control (Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Hyperlink). Although the code below does not give any errors, it does not work either, it does not show the tool tip:

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock();
var link = new Hyperlink();
var run = new Run();
run.Text = "http://www.twitter.com/.../";

ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.Content = "http://www.twitter.com/blablabla/longurl/";
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(link, toolTip);

link.Inlines.Add(run);
textBlock.Inlines.Add(link);
```

Is there a way to add tool tips to Inline objects inside a TextBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you known,  [`Hyperlink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279356) object is not a control, it seems like [`ToolTipService.ToolTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227608) attached property take no effect on it. As a workaround I recommend you to use [`RichTextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.aspx) instead of [`TextBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock). This is because `RichTextBlock` supports [`InlineUIContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx) class at the same time `TextBlock` doesn't support. [`HyperlinkButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242739) can be added to `InlineUIContainer`, since `ToolTipService.ToolTip` take effects on `HyperlinkButton`, so we can use a `RichTextBlock` with `HyperlinkButton` as follows to meet your requirements:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Italic>This is an inline bing: </Italic>      
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="bing" NavigateUri="http://www.bing.com" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="0,-3" xml:space="preserve">
                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip
                        Content="Offset ToolTip."
                        HorizontalOffset="20"
                        VerticalOffset="30" />
                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </HyperlinkButton>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        Mauris auctor tincidunt auctor.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a HyperlinkButton:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://www.mrlacey.com/" >
    <TextBlock Text="mrlacey.com">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="http://mrlacey.com/" />
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</HyperlinkButton>
```